# How do I fix java.lang.RuntimeException?

Tags: java, languagetool

I'm trying to use [LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org/usage/).
This is in the usage info:

```
> Using LanguageTool from other
> applications:    Start the stand-alone
> application and configure it to listen
> on a port that is not used yet (the
> default port, 8081, should often be
> okay). This way LanguageTool will run
> in server mode until you stop it. The
> client that wants to use LanguageTool
> can now just send its text to this
> URL:
> http://localhost:8081/?language=xx&text=my+text
```

I'm trying to use my IP `http://<IP HERE>:8081/?language=xx&text=my+text` but I keep getting

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: Access from (IP Address) denied

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Comment: It's possible that this mode only allows access from the local address, so you need to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as the address.

Comment: I may need to access this from another computer. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1) as suggested?

Comment: Peeking into [the code](https://languagetool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/languagetool/trunk/JLanguageTool/src/java/de/danielnaber/languagetool/server/LanguageToolHttpHandler.java) shows that this restriction is hard-coded. You might want to patch that.

Comment: Dian / Joachim: You may answer that question and then accept. Without it stays as lingering question, even if a solution is found.

Comment: @Joachim: Make your comment into an answer so I can mark it as correct answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restriction of only accepting connections from local network addresses (i.e. the loopback device) is hard-coded: [`LanguageToolHttpHandler`](https://languagetool.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/languagetool/trunk/JLanguageTool/src/java/de/danielnaber/languagetool/server/LanguageToolHttpHandler.java).

If you want to change it you'll have to change the source.

Comment: Update: starting with LanguageTool 1.7 there's a constructor that allows you to specify which IPs will have access. For the command line version, you can set the `--public` parameter to allow access from anywhere (disclaimer: I'm the LanguageTool maintainer).